# Filter for SQL Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following query written

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (((SocialAndTags 
JOIN 
    SocialManagementTracker ON SocialAndTags.SMTrackerID = SocialManagementTracker.SocialID)
JOIN 
    ProgramCategories ON SocialAndTags.ProgramCategoriesID = ProgramCategories.ProgramID)
JOIN 
    TagCategories ON SocialAndTags.TagCategoriesID = TagCategories.TagID) 
WHERE 
    InitialComment > '2020-03-16 00:00:00.999' 
    AND InitialComment < '2020-03-17 23:59:59.999'
ORDER BY 
    SMTrackerID DESC
```

This executes no problem.

Here is my issue. I have 3 tables. `TagCategories` tables holds the ID/Tag Name. `SocialManagementTracker` holds the Item and more details. `SocialAndTags` table has a unique ad and is pulling the `TagCategories` and `SocialManagementTracker` unique IDs.

When users are entering multiple tags for an item, its appearing the in the SocialAndTags table twice, which is how I set it up. How do I then use the above query to filer out the duplicate item results?

Or did I do this backwards and I should have added another column(s) to my SocialAndTags table?

Comment: post your table structure, data and required output.

Comment: If you have proper constraints, there can be no "duplicates". But one can guess that you don't manage natural keys - rather everything is based on identity columns. If so, then you need to either adjust your schema (better) or adjust your query to accommodate the schema problem. But no one can tell you without DDL and sample data.

Comment: And get rid of the parentheses around your joins - they only add clutter and confusion. They are not needed.

Comment: Thanks all. I typically do not write or work with SQL taking over for another dev due to the outbreak.

Comment: @SMor you are correct. everything is just based on identity columns. I will rework how i've set this up.

Answer (score 0):

I've reviewed my database and found I was referencing the wrong foreign key. I also used DISTINCT to get the results I required.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
SocialID, ProgramArea, Description, SocialURL, InitialComment, DaysToResolve, ResolutionDate FROM 
SocialAndTags 
JOIN SocialManagementTracker ON SocialAndTags.SMTrackerID = SocialManagementTracker.SocialID
JOIN ProgramCategories ON SocialAndTags.ProgramCategoriesID = ProgramCategories.ProgramID
WHERE 
InitialComment > '2020-03-16 00:00:00.999' 
AND InitialComment < '2020-03-17 23:59:59.999'
ORDER BY ResolutionDate, InitialComment DESC
```